# How to delete rows in Table1 where COUNT of WHERE in Table2 is greater than 0?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, left-join

I have [Table1] with user ID and [Table2] with the same user ID (left join) and column "open" with number of readed messages. I want to delete all users from [Table1] which has all rows in [Table2] with "open" column value < 1. I trying to select them first, but it gives SQL errors:

Trying 1:

```
SELECT pg_acymailing_subscriber.*,
       COUNT(DISTINCT case when pg_acymailing_userstats.open > 0 end) as readc
LEFT JOIN `pg_acymailing_userstats`
    ON pg_acymailing_subscriber.subid=pg_acymailing_userstats.subid
WHERE pg_acymailing_subscriber.subid=24 AND readc > 0;
```

Trying 2:

```
SELECT *
FROM `pg_acymailing_subscriber`
LEFT JOIN `pg_acymailing_userstats`
    ON pg_acymailing_subscriber.subid=pg_acymailing_userstats.subid
WHERE COUNT(DISTINCT case when pg_acymailing_userstats.open > 0 /*If user doesn't have rows with "open" column value > 0, we select it if whole rows numer is 0*/
                     end) < 1
  and pg_acymailing_subscriber.subid=24;
```

Comment: First query has no FROM.

Comment: Second query needs a sub-query to do the counting.

Comment: What's the nature of this "open" column? Is it an int or does it need to be counted? You speak like it's a value in the column ("where open < 1") but you write your queries like it needs to be grouped and counted.

Comment: Screenshots for better understanding: http://i.imgur.com/34JTn8N.png and http://i.imgur.com/Rss1vuZ.png

Comment: @jarlh, because I specified table before ".*" (after SELECT). I was thinked it will work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If performance is not an issue, it's probably easiest to build this with a subquery.

My understanding of your logic is that you want to delete all users from [Table1] that do not have any rows in [Table2] where `open > 0`, is that a correct paraphrasing of your requirement?

```
select * from pg_acymailing_subscriber where subid not in
( select subid from pg_acymailing_userstats where open > 0 )
```

If that shows the correct records, delete as follows:

```
delete from pg_acymailing_subscriber where subid not in
( select subid from pg_acymailing_userstats where open > 0 )
```

Comment: It's okay, I deleted rows in two tables, but then I need to delete rows also in current (userstats) table too: `DELETE from pg_acymailing_userstats where subid not in
( select subid from pg_acymailing_userstats where open > 0 );`, it gives me error: 1093 - Table 'pg_acymailing_userstats' is specified twice, both as a target for 'DELETE' and as a separate source for data

Comment: SOLVED! `DELETE from pg_acymailing_userstats where pg_acymailing_userstats.subid not in
(select * from (select subid from pg_acymailing_userstats where open > 0) t);`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter on results of aggregate functions you need GROUP BY and HAVING clauses, like e.g.

```
SELECT pg_acymailing_subscriber.userid,
       COUNT(DISTINCT case when pg_acymailing_userstats.open > 0 end) as readc
FROM `pg_acymailing_subscriber`
LEFT JOIN `pg_acymailing_userstats`
    ON pg_acymailing_subscriber.subid=pg_acymailing_userstats.subid
WHERE pg_acymailing_subscriber.subid=24
GROUP BY pg_acymailing_subscriber.userid
HAVING readc > 0;
```

I guessed that the user ID column is called userid. I might not have the quoting correct, but that's easy to repair.

And the `HAVING readc > 0` might or might not be correct syntax in mysql.
If it's not, you write `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT case when pg_acymailing_userstats.open > 0 end) > 0`

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly you questio you want delete the rows in table1 related to id in table2 whit  the sum of all open message is < 1
this should be the select

```
  select table1.userID
  from table1 
  inner  join table2 on table1.userID = table2.userID 
  group by table1.userID
  havine sum(open)<1
```

and then you could use a delete like

```
  detele 
  from table1 
  inner  join table2 on table1.userID = table2.userID 
  group by table1.userID
  havine sum(open)<1
```